# Woher kommt der Ausdruck "doppelt gemoppelt"?

Tags: etymology, phrase

Es ist leicht, Links zur Bedeutung zu finden:

- Bastian Sick: [Zweifach doppelt gemoppelt](https://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-zweifach-doppelt-gemoppelt-a-373614.html), *Der Spiegel*, 28.09.2005
- [Doppelt gemoppelt](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelt_gemoppelt) (Wikipedia; wird weitergeleitet auf [Pleonasmus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasmus), 29.12.2020).

Aber zunächst sieht ja *gemoppelt* wie ein Partizip aus, nur kenne ich dazu kein passendes Verb und mir ist auch sonst die Herkunft unbekannt.

Comment: Mit Sicherheit nicht relevant, aber es scheint, dass im deutschen Forge of Empires *moppeln* kurz ist für *motivieren/polieren* oder *mopo* (da werden Münzen poliert).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Den Ausdruck *doppelt gemoppelt* scheint seit dem Ende der 1940er-Jahre im Umlauf zu sein.

[image: doppelt gemoppelt]

Die genaue Herkunft ist meines Wissens ungeklärt. Es gibt im Deutschen die Wörter "Moppel" und "moppeln"; beide werden umgangssprachlich verwendet. Das erste bezeichnet einen molligen (dicken) Menschen, Hund oder Katze. Das zweite Wort "moppeln" bedeutet u. a. "Sex haben". Was der Begriff "doppelt gemoppelt" allerdings damit zu tun haben soll, ist für mich schleierhaft. Es gibt auch noch den Wischmopp, der auch für eine Erklärung herhalten könnte. Ich hüte mich aber vor Interpretationen, da mir keine glaubwürdige Quelle vorliegt.

Vielleicht bedeutet auch "gemoppelt" in diesem Zusammenhang nichts Spezifisches, und der Ursprung liegt einfach im Klangspiel, das aus der Zusammensetzung der beiden Wörter "doppelt" und "gemoppelt" entsteht.

Comment: Bei der Bundeswehr hieß der Mobile Generator zur Stromerzeugung „Moppel“, was vermutlich irgendwie von „mobil“ und „Elektrizität“ kommt. Wie das dazu passt, weiß ich aber auch nicht.

Answer (score 8):

Wieder mal sind wir [nicht die ersten](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2011/06/11/doppelt-gemoppelt/), die diese Diskussion anstoßen.

Hilfreich finde ich:

> Im Lothringischen Wörterbuch findet sich der Eintrag
>
> > ge-moppelt adj. Bo. pausbäckig, fett. — vgl. ElsWB els. 1, 697 Moppel dicker Mensch u. baier. 1, 1633 Moppel Mops.
>
> Mir erscheint der Erklärungsansatz, der auf ‘dick’ basiert, recht plausibel.

Comment: Der Moppel ist aber sicherlich von Mopp, viz. En mope. Ein Verb moppeln, *es moppelt* fehlt in der Argumentation soweit.

Answer (score 6):

Das [Südhessische Wörterbuch](https://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/rsrec/sn/shwb/entry/moppeln) sagt in Spalte 2, Zeile 24:

> 2. a) einen, sich in warme Kleider dick einhüllen, s. an-, ein-moppeln. 
>      b) doppelt gemoppelt zweifach dasselbe getan (...) Dobbeld gemobbeld hält besser Offb.

Die Frage bleibt erstmal, wieso hält das besser, hat es nicht doch, wie "Gast" schrieb, was mit kleben/leimen zu tun? Doch meine jüngste Vermutung ist: "Nein! **Es hält besser** warm."

Dass das *warm* unterschlagen wird kommt mir sprachlich zwar ungewöhnlich vor. Solche Sprachfiguren sind wohl eher selten. Ob es im Südhessischen üblicher ist, weiß ich nicht.

Aber von Splattne adoptiere ich den Hinweis auf den sprachspielerischen Charakter, der für die Verbreitung einer Phrase des Dialekts gesorgt haben könnte.

Comment: Das scheint mir im Gegensatz zu den anderen Antworten eine einleuchtende Erklärung zu sein.

Answer (score 5):

Von allen Antworten bietet die von userunknown die beste Erklärung, ist aber noch nicht völlig ausreichend zum Verständnis.

Die Wortkombination "doppelt gemoppelt" tritt nicht nur isoliert wie z.B. in "das ist doch doppelt gemoppelt" auf, sondern wird häufig mit "hält besser" fortgesetzt. Schon das alleine legt die Vermutung nahe, dass der Ausdruck im Zusammenhang damit steht, etwas aneinander zu befestigen. Im [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/doppelt_gemoppelt_h%C3%A4lt_besser) findet man dazu als Nebenformen

> doppelt hält besser, doppelt **genäht** hält besser

Das von user unknown genannte [Südhessischen Wörterbuch](https://www.lagis-hessen.de/de/subjects/index/sn/shwb) gibt weitere Informationen. Die Suchfunktion liefert

> zu **moppeln**: Spalte 752 2.a)

[image]

> zu **zusammenmoppeln**: Spalte 936 Zeile 15

[image]

> zu **zusammennoppeln**: Spalte 937

[image]

> zu **noppeln**: Spalte 1003

[image]

"Moppeln" hat also mit aller Wahrscheinlichkeit im Kontext "doppelt gemoppelt" die Bedeutung **nähen** und dürfte aus dem hessischen bzw. südwestdeutschen Sprachraum stammen. Vgl. auch U. Hus Antwort.

Eine weitere Referenz ist das [Lexikon der Redensarten. Bedeutung und Herkunft von A - Z](https://ia800709.us.archive.org/0/items/LexikonDerRedensarten.BedeutungUndHerkunftVonAZ/Lexikon%20der%20Redensarten.%20Bedeutung%20und%20Herkunft%20von%20A-Z.pdf) (Phoenix Verlag):

> **doppelt gemoppelt:** (unnötig) zweimal; scherzhafte Wendung, in der die Verdopplung schon in der Doppelgliedrigkeit des Ausdrucks zum Vorschein kommt. Das Wort "moppeln" bedeutet verknüpfen, verbinden.

Comment: eh, und *jemanden vermöbeln* ist dann im Gegenteil, *auseinandernehmen, aufknüpfen*, möglicher Weise? Ich sehe nur nicht, wie man von *nopeln* zu *moppeln* kommt, etwa *dsamm'n-nobbeln* stärker verkürzt mkt assimilation "*dsa-mobbeln*", was dann erstmal halb nach *zu-* klingt (in welcher Form es sicherlich auch existiert, was u.a. überhaupt erst die bedeutung "schließen" für 'zu' erklärt, der gegenüber syn. "'ran" nicht wirklich überzeugt, i.e. *mach die Türe zu*).

Answer (score 2):

Moppeln kommt von der Tätigkeit kleben/leimen, um genau zu sein, Kleber auftragen. Trägt man den Kleber auf beide Flächen auf so hält es später besser. Moppeln kommt von Mopp, dass ist quasi der Pinsel mit dem der Kleister aufgetragen wird. Der Mopp wie ein Wischmopp aufgebaut nur kleiner .

Comment: Dass ein Mopp ein Pinsel sein soll, lässt sich nirgends finden - gibt es einen Beleg dafür? Die Antwort klingt ansonsten nämlich plausibel...

Comment: Das klingt absolut hanebüchen. Wir haben nicht den ersten April, aber es war trotzdem ein guter Versuch, lieber Gast.

Comment: @Philipp während *doppelt gemoppelt* sehr hochklassig klingt oder wie jetzt?

Comment: @vectory Ich muss gestehen, ich kann heute nicht mehr nachvollziehen, was mich zu diesem Kommentar getrieben hat. Missverständnis vermutlich.

Comment: @Philipp ... oder die fehlenden Belege...

Answer (score 1):

Eine weitere Idee wäre Moppel als Referenz auf einen dicken Hund zu sehen: ein Moppel ist ein molliger Hund mit Fettwalzen, wenn er nun doppelt-gemoppelt ist, dann ist er noch viel unnötiger moppelig (d.h fett) als es sein müsste, also doppelt so viele Fettwalzen.

Comment: ein Hund ist aber nicht gemoppelt, sondern moppelig oder etwa doppelt moppelig. Daher ist dieser Vorschlag nicht schlüssiger als alle anderen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich glaube nicht, dass die oben genannten Wörter etwas mit dem "gemoppelt" in "doppelt gemoppelt" zu tun haben. Leider schweigen sich auch alle gängigen Wörterbücher (Duden, das Grimmsche Wörterbuch, das Wörterbuch der deutschen Gegenwartssprache) zur Etymologie des Begriffs aus.
Am plausibelsten erscheint mir als Linguist, dass es sich um ein Wortspiel mit "doppelt" handelt. Das würde auch erklären, dass es nur das Partizip Perfekt gibt, aber keinen entsprechenden Infinitiv. Außerdem kommt das Wort nur in dieser einen Redewendung vor.

Comment: Es wurde doch von @UserUnknown oben ein dialektisches Verb *moppeln* "sich in warme Kleider dick einhüllen" gefunden. Woher das nu wieder stammt ist fraglich, sicherlich trägt Wortspiel in jeder Hinsicht eine große Rolle bei dieser Frage, aber was ein einzelner User bar jeder Begründung zu glauben mag, hat leider gar keinen Erklärwert.

Answer (score 1):

Bei uns (Südwestdeutschland) hatten früher die Näherinnen die Überwendlichmaschine als "**Moppelchen**" bezeichnet. Das hing vielleicht auch mit der damals rundlichen Käferartigen Form dieser Nähmaschinen zusammen.

Answer (score 0):

Ich habe da keine sichere Antwort drauf, aber "moppeln" hat zumindest einige Google Treffer, die es als Ausdruck für "Sex haben" angeben.

Von daher könnte ich mir die passend zur Bedeutung (etwas unnötig zweimal tun) vorstellen, dass es bildlich bedeutet zweimal Sex haben und es kommt doch nur ein Kind bei raus.

Comment: +1 – eine schöne Erklärung, wenn ich auch fürchte: *falsch*. Ebenso überflüssig ist es ja auch 2x mit dem Wischmop daherzugehen, und zu reinigen, was bereits sauber ist. Und ein doppelter Rollmops? Als Matjesesser kenne ich Doppelmatjes, welches 2x Filet ist, mit einem Rest Gräte zusammengehalten, und im Gegensatz zum einfachen Matjes(-filet) eben die doppelte Portion.

Comment: Also bezogen auf den Wischmopp wäre da ja wohl eher "doppelt gemoppt", oder? Und eine doppelte Portion Rollmops nährt dich doch doch auch doppelt. Würde beides für mich keinen Sinn machen ...

Comment: Gibt es das Verb *moppen*? Ich stimme zu: eher *moppen* als *moppeln*, welches an den *hoppelnden* Hasen erinnert. Und zwei Portionen Rollmops essen würde man noch lange nicht *moppeln* nennen können, auch nicht *rollmoppe[l]n*. Beim Sex-Haben erscheint mir eine Verbform wie *moppeln* eher denkbar. *Vögeln* ist ja in der Fauna auch kein Wort.

Comment: Re *gemoppt* nicht *gemoppelt*? Schonmal von *dichterischer Freiheit* gehört?

Comment: Ich würde eher eine verniedlichte Analogie zu En *fucked* sehen, da das vollführen des Beischlafs nie nicht negativ bewitzelt wird. Es würde mich zumindest überraschen, oder der Phrase eine ironischere Note geben als sie heute hat.

Answer (score 0):

Aufgrund der Reputationsgeschichte auf dieser Seite kann ich den Beitrag von "Gast" nicht kommentieren:

> Moppeln kommt von der Tätigkeit kleben/leimen, um genau zu sein, Kleber auftragen. Trägt man den Kleber auf beide Flächen auf so hält es später besser. Moppeln kommt von Mopp, dass ist quasi der Pinsel mit dem der Kleister aufgetragen wird. Der Mopp wie ein Wischmopp aufgebaut nur kleiner .

Das mit dem doppelt verkleben/leimen ist eine Theorie, die ich von Antiquitätenhändlern gehört habe. So gibt es manchmal Stücke z. B. aus Holz, bei denen eine alte Leimung erneuert wurde. Da spricht man von doppelt gemoppelt. Weil neuer Leim hauchdünn auf den alten Leim aufgetragen wurde.

Comment: Wenn der Begriff im Antiquitätenhandel quasi zur Fachsprache gehört, sollte sich doch ein Beleg dafür finden, oder?

Comment: Das klingt beeindruckend, dass es Dir gelungen ist, gleich mehrere Antiquitätenhändler zu bewegen, ihre Leimtheorien zu offenbaren. Wobei man ja sagt, dass Antiquitätenhändler nicht nur Holz leimen. Nur ist, wer alte Möbel verscheuert, nicht deshalb Experte für Sprachetymologie. Wieso heißt es gemoppelt und nicht gemoppt, wenn es vom Mopp kommt? Inwiefern ist der Leimpinsel ähnlich wie ein Mopp https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mopp aufgebaut? Ich geh' Dir nicht auf den Leim! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Man suche einfach eine Alliteration, die sich auf "doppelt" reimt. Verben für "es irgendwie hinbekommen" gibt es unendlich: fräggeln, rumwürchen, friemeln, rumfummeln, zubbeln usw.. Ein Moppel assoziiert ziemlich harmlos, aber abfällig und scherzhaft jemanden, der unbeholfen, dicklich ist. In der Art wird man auf das sehr einprägsame "doppelt gemoppelt" gekommen sein. "Moppeln" also als frei erfundenes weiteres Synonym.

Answer (score 0):

Moppel wird auch oft mit einem (dicken) Hasen in Verbindung gebracht. Ich denke, dass es v.a. ein Wortspiel ist.

Comment: Willkommen bei German.SE. Liegt es am Hasen oder am Dicksein?

Comment: Verwechselst Du vielleicht moppeln mit hoppeln? ;)

Answer (score -1):

Meine idee: Aus Englisch mop ist etwas sauber machen, also "doppelt gemoppelt" ist zwei Mal umsonst etwas sauber machen.

Comment: -1, denn es heißt leider "moppen" und nicht "moppeln", wie auch schon in den Kommentaren in der Antwort von Hinek angemerkt.

Comment: Außerdem heißt die Redewendung ja "doppelt gemoppelt hält besser" und nicht "hält auch nicht besser".